# PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am making Webservice call thru TLS connection(https) in Tomcat 7.x

While calling the WebService, I am getting following Error. What would be the issue? I have tried creating Certificates and CA.

FYI - https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/create-your-own-certificate-and-ca

I imported CA certificate and other certificates and still I am getting this issue. Please advice.

```
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://localhost:8443/myDomain/MyService?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
... 37 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:632)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
```

I am testing Certificates by creating locally. So I followed these steps.

Keys>keytool -genkey -alias TLS -keystore TLSKeyStore.jks -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA
Keys>keytool -export -alias TLS -file TLS.cer -keystore TLSKeyStore.jks
Keys>keytool -certreq -alias TLS -keystore TLSKeyStore.jks -file TLS.csr

CA>set RANDFILE=rand

CA>openssl req -new -keyout TLSkey.pem -out TLSreq.pem -config C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg

CA>openssl x509 -signkey TLSkey.pem -req -days 3650 -in TLSreq.pem -out TLSroot.cer -extensions v3_ca

CA>openssl x509 -CA TLSroot.cer -CAkey TLSkey.pem -CAserial serial.txt -req -in ../Keys/TLS.csr -out ../Keys/TLSTestCA.cer -days 365

Keys>keytool -import -alias TLSCA -file ../CA/TLSroot.cer -keystore TLSKeyStore.jks
Keys>keytool -import -alias TLS -file TLSTestCA.cer -keystore TLSKeyStore.jks

Answer (score 13):

**Here's an overall summary of how to import certificates to fix the following error:**

> Error while trying to execute request.
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

**How to import certificates**

1. Go to URL in your browser, click on HTTPS certificate chain (little lock symbol next to URL address) to **export the certificate**

   - Click "more info" > "security" > "show certificate" > "details" > "export..".
   - Save as **`.der`**
   - Repeat for any certificates you need to import
2. Locate **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts**
3. **Import all *.der files** into the cacerts file using the following:

   ```
   sudo keytool -import -alias mysitestaging -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file staging.der
   sudo keytool -import -alias mysiteprod -keystore  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file prod.der
   sudo keytool -import -alias mysitedev -keystore  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file dev.der
   ```
4. The default keystore **password is 'changeit'**
5. You can view the change that you made with this command that shows the Certificate fingerprint.

   ```
   keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
   ```
6. If this doesn't solve the problem, try adding these java options as arguments:

   ```
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
   ```

My guess is that you might have missed a step. I was having the same error until I realized I imported the wrong certificate

Comment: I had to add similar lines for `bin/netbeans` script: `-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$netbeans_jdkhome/jre/lib/security/cacerts"` and `-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=""` then Apache Netbeans 15 was able to connect to any plugin central.

Comment: @Katie How can I verify if I do not know the fingerprint of certificate

Answer (score 9):

Finally I got the way to solve this issue.

Refer this [InstallCert.java](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/698088/#msg_698088) in this link. Run this program as Standalone by passing arguments as **localhost:9443** and Program creates **jssecacerts** file under eclipse.
Copy this **jssecacerts** file into your JDK_HOME\jre\lib\security\ folder. That should solve the issue

Happy TLS setup!!!

Comment: A slightly modified version of that program is avaialble at http://infposs.blogspot.it/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html
It solves an issue with Java 7 (an UnsupportedOperationExcetpion when you run InstallCert the second time to check whether the certificate has been correctly installed).

Comment: @Pino the blog deleted

Comment: @DimasLanjaka, the internet Archive has a copy of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20161229182623/http://infposs.blogspot.it/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html

Comment: thanks. i copied the certificate some code to apply with okhttp client TLS SSL interceptor to accept all TLS hostnames