# Build failed - unable to find valid certification path

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I am getting the following error when I try to build my app using ant & ivy

```
buildtools/task-gae.xml:432: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This code was done by a development company and I have no experience with ant nor ivy. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947517/pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexce) is this the way to fix it? The only issue is I'm not sure what port to pass from local host and also I don't know where the file would be created and I have no idea where JDK_HOME\jre\lib\security\ folder is.

Comment: Your build is accessing an SSL protected site that is using an untrusted certificate. It's a very common and painful problem to fix client-side. Normally I tell people to spend some money and setup the remote server with properly signed certificate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this error was actually because I didn't have google app engine installed for the build. Everything seems to be working fine now.